# Trying a dynamically selected menu ..stuck in some part

Tags: c

The idea is to have an array containing 10 strings.

Trying to print a menu dynamically with the selected options. Here i am trying to pull the stings from array to a structure...but i not getting it...if i assign the string directly to structure variable i can read it.

Please somebody explain me what is going wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct some_numbers{
       int id;
       char *somestring[10];
       }numb;

    int main()
    {
    int i = 0;         
    numb *new_numb;

    char *arr[10]= {0};

    for(i; i<2; i++)
    {
           printf("Please enter %dth name:\n",i);
           scanf("%s",arr+i);
          //i am printing it agian to confirm that it is stored in said locations
           printf("%s\n",arr+i);
    }

    new_numb = (struct numb *)malloc(sizeof(numb)*4);

    //If i assign the string dirctly then i can print it as follow

    new_numb->somestring[0] = "MY_number";

    printf("%s\n",new_numb->somestring[0]);
       //I am trying to copy string from an arry and print it again....but not working 

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
             strcpy(new_numb->somestring[i], arr+i);
             printf("%s\n",new_numb->somestring[i]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Why is new_numb being given 4 times the size of numb?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for each `char *` in `arr` as well as `new_num->somestring`.

With `char * arr[10]` you have created an array with 10 `char *`s but each of them (`arr[0], arr[1]`) will required memory to hold string.

Similar for `new_numb->somestring` array.

You can modify the code something like

```
for(i; i<2; i++)
{
       printf("Please enter %dth name:\n",i);

       //allocate memory to hold string of max 100 chars, you may want to change that.
       arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

       scanf("%s",arr+i);
      //i am printing it agian to confirm that it is stored in said locations
       printf("%s\n",arr+i);

}
```